# Does removing an iPhone from my icloud account also erase the data?

Tags: icloud, find-my-iphone

I lost my iPhone 6S recently. I think it fell off my car and was crushed because it has been offline (according to Find My iPhone) ever since. I want to erase the phone and remove it from my iCloud account since the phone is gone.

However, I can't erase the phone until it comes back online. I do have the option to remove the device from my iCloud account. If I remove the phone from my iCloud account, does that also erase the data? The phone has a password on it, will it continue to be locked in case someone finds it after I have removed it from my iCloud account?

Answer (score 1):

The erase command can't be delivered until the device connects to the internet. The same with issuing a passcode lock.

The device will remain unlocked, unprotected, unearned until such time as it connects to Apple's servers.

That being said, a destroyed phone is unlikely to be unlocked or even work, but there's a chance your data is vulnerable if you cannot assure destruction by locating it and shredding it (or equivalent).

Comment: The phone does have a passcode lock, so even if someone picks it up, it should be safe. Do you know what will happen to the phone/data if I remove the device from my iCloud account? Would it become unlocked somehow? Or will it stay locked even if it is removed?